# testing objects with instanceof

Tags: javascript

```
var google = {  
    makeBeer : function(arg1,arg2){     
         alert([this instanceof google, arg1, arg2]);        
    }    
}

google.makeBeer('water','soda');
```

The above does not alert when i check `this instanceof google`, but the same code works when i do this.

```
var google = {  
    makeBeer : function(arg1,arg2){     
         alert([this instanceof Object, arg1, arg2]);        
    }    
}

google.makeBeer('water','soda');
```

the reference 'this' is instance of Object, why not the `Google Object`. How can i ensure that the instance is of that particular object in my case.

**Update to the same question:**

```
var newWay = {}
google.makeBeer.call(newWay, 'pepsi', 'coke');
```

In the above case i am passing the newWay object to my funcion makeBeer, how can i know that its newWay object here.

Comment: Even in your update, you still have a plain object. There is nothing unique about it.

Comment: @Mathletics: thats fine, but how come i can differentiate between these two...

Comment: You need to construct your object using this pattern:
function Way() { }
var newWay = new Way()

Comment: Are you asking "how can I differentiate between the two" or are you telling me that you already can?

Comment: The answer to your updated question is that you cannot know that the object reference passed to your function is referred to by a variable in the calling context. Such information is simply not made visible by the JavaScript runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN entry on instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

So unless you create the object with a unique constructor, something like:

```
var newWay = new Way(); // assuming you have defined an object Way
```

where `newWay instanceof Way === true`, you can't use instanceof to tell you anything other than that it is an object.

Comment: Excellent..... why is it so? why can't it without having an unique constructor... what does an object literal refers to...

Comment: @Kevin an object literal is simply a `new Object()` which contains key value pairs. All `Objects` are simply that, `Objects`.

Comment: Why in the later case its not working unless i construct it, if all are objects.

Comment: The purpose of `instanceof` is to tell you when you have an _instance_ of a specific kind of object, and the only way to do that is to have an object (not `Object`, per se) which has its own `prototype`.

Comment: var newWay = {}
google.makeBeer.call(newWay, 'pepsi', 'coke'); this aint working though newWay is an object but newWay = new newWay() works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26110/discussion-between-mathletics-and-kevin)

Answer (score 1):

The object referred to by the variable "google" is in fact just a plain object. The identifier "google" is just a variable name. The `instanceof` operator tells where an object came from, not what variable(s) happen to be referring to it.

Comment: I have updated my question where we to make a call method in a function... in that context can i refer